# Open A New Layout, Then Return to the Previous

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have my `main.xml` layout.  From here, the user fills in information, and is to click a button that should bring them to another `describe.xml` layout.

The question is: how do I get it so that you can press a button on `main.xml` to open up `describe.xml`, then when  you hit a button on the `describe.xml`, you return to `main.xml` without any information previously inputted into `main.xml` lost?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Theres some info in here about saving states. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to do this

1) When you start Activity `describe Activity` don't finish() `main Activity` so that when you finish `describe Activity` main Activity will be resume without and lost of data

2) If you want to get data from describe Activity to main Activity you can start describe Activity by calling `startActivityForResult` and you can get result from describe Activity to main Activity

3) You can also save data to preference file

Comment: Step 1 and 3 seem easy enough, so I'll try those out.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just store your information in a SharedPreference or a file or some static field in the override onPaused() method, and read out and fill information in the onResume() method.

Comment: That sounds perfectly reasonable.  I'll give that a try.